# Botulism risk in garlic confit

Tags: food-science, garlic

I recently made garlic confit and left it at room temperature overnight to cool. I then looked up storage for the garlic confit and noticed that lots of articles say there's a high risk for botulism and it should be cooled as quickly as possible. Do you think it's still safe to use my garlic confit? How long would it actually take to develop?

Comment: This is potentially unsafe.